# What do you call this thing that seems to be related to electriticity distribution?

Tags: word-request

[image]

I honestly have no idea what this is. Is it a power distribution board? I am not sure what this is because I am not an electrician, but I was thinking it was a power distribution board, but since a power distribution board looks like this:

[image]

I thought it might be something else.

Comment: Maybe you should ask in [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: They are both power distribution 'boards', or 'panels'. These things come in many different shapes, sizes, and types, domestic and industrial.

Comment: In the USA, the first picture is a "breaker box."  Or "electrical panel."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK, electricians might call this a "[consumer unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_unit)".  Normal people might say "fusebox" (even though it contains no actual fuses).

The US practice is to call these "[distribution boards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_board)", or more colloquially a "breaker panel" The US and the UK are very different in terms of electricity codes, and things that are normal in the UK are illegal in the US and vice-versa. Apart from very common words like "wire" most of the technical language is different.

Comment: In the US, I've never heard it called a "distribution board", only a "(circuit) breaker panel", but I'm not an electrician and it does look like electricians call it a distribution board.